# Cannot receive the quest revealing the unseen

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am able to talk to Mirabelle but it wont let me accept the quest "Revealing the Unseen" is it a fixable glitch?

Comment: but also i thought they patched this glitch?

Comment: Bethesda hasn't. If you're on PC you can install the mod called "Unifficial Skyrim Patch", which reportedly fixes the glitch.

Comment: oh okay im on xbox